# Flutter app displays black screen after trying to add a google account and then returning to app screen

Tags: flutter, google-signin, flutter-dependencies

Using the google_sign_in package to allow users to sign in to firebase using a Google account. I discovered a bug that displays a black screen in the background instead of the application after trying to sign in with an added account and returning to the main screen without completing the sign-in process.

Steps to reproduce:

[Login Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdrO3.jpg) Click on Sign In with Google

[Google Sign In Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdx8b.jpg) Click on add another account

[Add account screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyVqC.jpg) Navigate back to the app before creating a new account

[Google Sign In Options with black screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fU7jg.jpg)

The issue is here I do not want the screen to be black but to be the same as the previous Google Sign In Options image. I have doubts that it might be due to the loss of the context but I am not sure what is causing the issue.

The function I am using is the signIn() method from the google_sign_in package on version 4.5.4

All other aspects of the package are functioning correctly. I am able to sign in with an account and have it authenticate the user through to the homepage

Answer (score 1):

< style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
use this in styles.xml